# C++ Fastest Way to Hit a URL

Tags: c++, c, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to ping a URL on a server in the middle of my high-performance C++ application, where every millisecond is critical.  I don't care about the return data from the query... I just need to send a HTTP request to a specific URL (to cause it to load), and I'm trying to find the most effective, non-blocking method to accomplish this.

My application uses Boost::ASIO, but most methods to do this seem to involve building and tearing down sockets each time (which might unfortunately be necessary), but I'm hoping there's a basic C/C++ socket one-liner that won't cause any overhead, memory leaks, blocking, etc.  Just quickly open a socket, shoot the HTTP request off, and move along.

And this will need to happen thousands of times per second, so sockets and overhead is important (don't want to flood the OS).

Anyone have any advice on the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I guess you have no control on the server side. You want to do some (D)DOS? ;)

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"[¹](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). Get it working first and then *measure* to see where your hotspots are. From C++ it's pretty hard to get around the fact that HTTP requires TCP connections.

Comment: Is using a single [persistent HTTP connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) a possibility?

Comment: It's not for DOS, lol - it's communicating with an enterprise API (sending notifications).  It's the same destination with each request, so a persistent connection is a possibility... I've never done that before though.  Thanks so much!  :)

Comment: I've never used it personally, but I'm aware of [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/) as being a high-quality library that works with boost::asio and and has builtin HTTP support. I'd check it against your requirements, at least as a starting point.

Comment: Why do you need to use the HTTP protocol?  Can't you just have a socket server listening for connections?

Answer (score 1):

With thousands of notifications sent per second, I can't imagine opening a socket connection for each one.  That would probably be too inefficient due to the overhead.  So, as Casey suggested, try using a dedicated connection.

Since it sounds like you are doing quite a bit of processing on your main thread, you might consider creating a worker thread for the socket work.  You will probably need to use thread synchronization objects like a mutex or critical section to single thread the code - at least when updating a container (probably a queue) from your main thread and reading it from the worker thread.

Comment: My app is already multi-threaded.  I have no experience with a dedicated connection like that though.  Do you have any example code I could see?  Thanks!

Comment: I have not used http before.  I have used ASIO for a Windows C++ client that connects to multiple servers using SSL.  However, there are several ASIO examples utilizing HTTP from this [link](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html).